# Copy file to directory

Tags: c#, .net, file, copy

Is there no .NET library call for copying a file to a directory? All library calls I found (e.g. `File.Copy()` or `FileInfo.CopyTo()`) do only support copying a file to another fully specified *file*.

```
string file = "C:\Dir\ect\ory\file.txt";
string dir = "C:\Other\Directory";

File.Copy(file, dir); // does not work, requires filename
```

Is there a library call? If no, what's the best way to write my own utility, do I really have to use `Path.GetFileName()`?

Comment: why do you want to avoid Path.GetFileName()?

Comment: I just hoped there is already such a library call in the .NET framework.

Comment: such a method might be usefull but i guess specifying the filename is a good thing.

Comment: though if you just want to hide the intant you can create an extension method. that does all the work of fetching the filename etc. may i write one for you?

Comment: I already have one now, thanks. Contents = winSharp93's answer.

Comment: that isn't an extension method.

Comment: May the downvoter please elaborate why he did downvote the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do I really have to use Path.GetFileName()?

Exactly:

```
string destination = Path.Combine(dir, Path.GetFileName(file));
Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
File.Copy(file, destination);
```

Comment: OK, this is exactly what I have as well, a pity there is nothing else, thanks anyways. (accepting answer as soon as it is possible, 8min...)

Answer (score 1):

Try this example

```
public class SimpleFileCopy
{
 static void Main()
 {
    string fileName = "test.txt";
    string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder";
    string targetPath =  @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\SubDir";        
    string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
    string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);      
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);      

}
```

}